# I can drag, but cannot drop external event in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, fullcalendar

I am using jquery-ui 1.12.1 and fullcalendar.js 3.4 in angular 4. I am able to drag events on the screen but when I try to drop event on the calendar the drop property doesn't fire and events just reverts back.

Here is my part of the code:

HTML:

```
<div id='external-events'>
 <div id='external-events-listing'>
  <h4>Draggable Events</h4>
  <div class='fc-event'>My Event 1</div>
  <div class='fc-event'>My Event 2</div>
  <div class='fc-event'>My Event 3</div>
  <div class='fc-event'>My Event 4</div>
  <div class='fc-event'>My Event 5</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
   calendarInit(){
  this.calendarOptions = {
    fixedWeekCount : false,
    defaultDate: '2016-09-12',
    editable: true,
    defaultTimedEventDuration: '01:00:00',
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    eventOverlap: (stillEvent, movingEvent) => {
      return stillEvent.allDay && !movingEvent.allDay;
    },
    droppable: true,
    drop: function(date, jsEvent) {
      console.log(date, jsEvent);

    },

    selectable: true, // TO DO

    defaultView: 'agendaDay',
    header: { center: 'agendaDay,agenda3Day' }, // buttons for switching between views
    views: {
      agenda3Day: {
          type: 'agenda',
          duration: { days: 3 },
          buttonText: '3 days',
          groupByDateAndResource: true
      }
    },
    viewRender: (view, element)=>{
      this.calendarMode = view.type;
    },

    eventClick: (calEvent) => {
      this.showConfirm(calEvent)
    },

    businessHours: {
      dow: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
      start: '5:00',
      end: '23:00',
    },

    resources: this.resources[this.resourceSection],
    events: [
      ...events...
      {
        resourceId: 2,
        title: 'Click for Google',
        url: 'http://google.com/',
        start: '2016-09-28',
        color: '#FFC107'        
      }
    ]
  }
}

externalEvents(){
  var externalEvents = {
    title: $.trim($('#external-events .fc-event').text()),        
  }; // creating event object and makes event text as its title

  $('#external-events .fc-event').data('externalEvents', externalEvents); //saving events into DOM

  $('#external-events .fc-event').draggable({
    revert: true,      // immediately snap back to original position
    revertDuration: 0,
    zIndex: 999      
  })

}
```

Does anybody know why I cannot drop external event? Thanks.

Comment: what happens if you remove `revert: true` from the draggables?

Comment: I havent tried to remove revert but if I set it to false then it just stays on the screen wherever I drop it.

Comment: can you make a StackSnippet or JSFiddle which demonstrates the issue, please? Could be something in the detail, but without a working environment to play with it's hard to try it out and say what exactly is the issue. You could also try reducing your calendar down to the code shown in the fullCalendar example at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dropping/droppable/, and then adding your other options, content, etc back in until it stops working again.

Comment: I will when I get home in 1 hour

Comment: I solved this buy moving all js files from index.html to anuglar-cli.json. I also stopped using <angular2-calendar> tag and replaced it with <div id="calendar"></div>. When I used the component the calendar was called twice. I will post the solution when I am eligible for it. Thanks for helping!

Comment: No problem. Glad you solved it. I often find the best way to narrow down strange problems like this is to start from the simplest code possible that is known to work, and then add the complexity gradually until you get a problem. Then you usually know exactly where your issue starts from. Makes debugging much easier!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research this is what I did and fullcalendar works perfectly.

First you have to install jquery and jquery-ui from npm

> npm install jquery --save
>
> npm install jquery-ui save

Download `jquery-ui` from the website and place it in `node_modules/jquery-ui/dist/` which I had to create.

Then move all your css and js files from index.html to your angular-cli.json. This is how my angular-cli.json looks like:

```
  "styles": [
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
    "../node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.css",
    "styles.scss"
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    "../node_modules/jquery-ui/dist/jquery-ui.min.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
    "../node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js",
    "../node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.js",
    "../node_modules/fullcalendar-scheduler/dist/scheduler.min.js"
  ]
```

In your `calendar.component.ts` add

`declare var $:any;
import * as moment from 'moment';`

and in your html use `<div id="calendar"></div>`

This will allow you to use jquery-ui with draggable/droppable events. 
I hope this helps to somebody!